# I would like to update the state of a widget in parallel to a subprocess running

Tags: python, subprocess, pyqt4

Here's the code:

```
def run_analyzer(self, analyzer, filename):
    is_set_to_zero = False

    p = subprocess.Popen([analyzer, filename], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    line_iterator = iter(p.stdout.readline, b"")
    for line in line_iterator:
        is_set_to_zero = self.progBar(str(line), is_set_to_zero)  

def progBar(self, text, set_to_zero):

    if set_to_zero == False:
        self.core_progress_bar.setMinimum(0)
        self.core_progress_bar.setMaximum(0)
        return True

    if 'DONE' in text:
        self.core_progress_bar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.core_progress_bar.setValue(100)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.core_progress_bar.reset()
```

The entire idea behind this is to have the progress bar in a 'busy' state while the analyzer is doing its thing. Once the final line (which includes the word DONE) has been passed to the progBar method, it will flash solid green and go back to being boring.

It works perfectly in debug mode.

However, when its run normally, while the analyzer is analyzing the bar isn't doing anything. As soon as it finishes, the program seems to finally remember that its supposed to do something with the progress bar and it flashes green, like I wanted it to.

Is there a way to have these things in the spotlight at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

QT will not update your gui while it's stuck in your method's loop, you have to move that loop into a class that inherits `QtCore.QThread` and create/connect a custom signal to that thread which will update your progress bar

some example here:

```
class Progress(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    def run():
        p = subprocess.Popen([analyzer, filename], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        line_iterator = iter(p.stdout.readline, b"")
        for line in line_iterator:
            self.emit( QtCore.SIGNAL('__updateProgressBar(int)', yourPercentNumber))


class YourMainClass:
    #blabla...
    self.progressThread = Progress()
    self.connect(self.progressThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("__updateProgressBar(int)"), self.progBar)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def progBar(percent):
        #blabla
```